# Why can't I return an object from my block?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, asynchronous, nsmutablearray

I'm trying to return a `NSMutableArray` from my block in my method, but when I add the line `return [responseString JSONValue];`, I get some compiler warnings.

```
- (NSMutableArray*)getTodayData:(NSDate*)today
{
        ASIFormDataRequest *request = [[[ASIFormDataRequest alloc] initWithURL:url] autorelease];
        [request setPostValue:[dateFormat stringFromDate:today] forKey:@"target_date"];
        NSError *error = [request error];

        [request setCompletionBlock:^{
            NSString *responseString;
            if (!error) {
                responseString = [request responseString];
                return [responseString JSONValue];
            } else {
                NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
            }
        }];
        [request setFailedBlock:^{
            NSString *responseString;
            if (!error) {
                responseString = [request responseString];
            } else {
                NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
            }
        }];
        [request startAsynchronous];
}
```

Comment: Could you please show the warnings the compiler gave?

Comment: What object is catching the return value?

Comment: `NSMutableArray` is catching it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `setCompletionBlock:` and `setFailedBlock:` methods in `ASIFormDataRequest` do not accept blocks with a return value. You need to restructure your code so that there is no return value.

For example:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [self getTodayData:self.datePicker.date];
}

- (void)getTodayData:(NSDate*)today
{
      self.appointmentsArray = [NSArray array]; // set it to an empty value now, so the table view displays nothing

      ASIFormDataRequest *request = [[[ASIFormDataRequest alloc] initWithURL:url] autorelease];
      [request setPostValue:[dateFormat stringFromDate:today] forKey:@"target_date"];
      NSError *error = [request error];

      [request setCompletionBlock:^{
          NSString *responseString;
          if (!error) {
              responseString = [request responseString];
              self.appointmentsArray = [responseString JSONValue];

              [self.appointmentsArrayTableView reloadData]; // I'm assuming you want to display the appointments in some view
          } else {
              NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
          }
      }];
      [request setFailedBlock:^{
          NSString *responseString;
          if (!error) {
              responseString = [request responseString];
          } else {
              NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
          }
      }];
      [request startAsynchronous];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

What are you expecting returning an object to do? Presumably the completion block that you hand to `ASIFormDataRequest` is declared as `void (^)()` (or `dispatch_block` or some other typedef which evaluates to `void (^)()`). Given this, the code calling the block isn't expecting a return value. It would be like implementing a method declared `- (void)foo` and trying to return an object from that; it just doesn't make sense.

**Edit:** After re-reading your code, I expect what you're really trying to do is returning a value from `-getTodayData:`. However you're executing an asynchronous request. The method `-getTodayData:` has *already returned* long before your block is executed.

Comment: Well, in my `viewDidLoad`, I have `self.appointmentsArray = [self getTodayData:self.datePicker.date];`.  How would I make this work?

Comment: Ok I saw your edited comment, so how would I change my code to make this work? I'm using this method to reload my `tableview` when the user changes the date of a `datepicker` to refresh the table, and also in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: @Jon: The simplest way is to stop using an asynchronous request, except doing network IO on the main thread synchronously is a *terrible* idea. You need to change your method so it accepts a completion block itself that it passes the data to instead of returning the object. Then the calling method passes a completion block that takes the array and updates the table with it. It's a rather different style of programming, but in a lot of ways it's better.

Comment: I got it fixed.  But do you really mean stop using `asynchronous` requests?

Comment: @Jon: If you do a synchronous request, then your block can modify a `__block` variable in the containing method, which is then returned from that method. Code-wise, it's the simplest. However, it's a really bad idea to do on the main thread.

Answer (score 1):

The block is defined as `void`. Think about how you are trying to interact with the block. What are you trying to return from the block? Who would it return to? How?

I think one misunderstanding you are having is dealing with asynchronous programming. Your method `- (NSMutableArray*)getTodayData:(NSDate*)today` is actually only sending a *request*. It is *not* returning an array. You send the request, and the request will execute the block once it is completed. But your program will have already returned from your `getTodayData:` method by the time the block gets executed. It will have *no* return value.

What you want to do instead is to use a [delegate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_%28programming%29#Design_pattern). When the block is executed at the completion of the request, you can notify the delegate that the response is now stored somewhere—preferably as an instance variable—and is now ready to be accessed.