# Returning NSDictionary from async code block?

Tags: objective-c, ios5, twitter, nsurlrequest

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [returning UIImage from block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9474018/returning-uiimage-from-block)

Hi I'm trying to return dictionary of json twitter data so i can use it in my application. How ever it is being called from a async block. I can not save it or return it any thoughts?

```
  -(NSDictionary *)TweetFetcher
    {

    TWRequest *request = [[TWRequest alloc] initWithURL:
                          [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://search.twitter.com/search.json?
    q=iOS%205&rpp=5&with_twitter_user_id=true&result_type=recent"] parameters:nil 
    requestMethod:TWRequestMethodGET];


    [request performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse 
    *urlResponse, 
    NSError *error)
     {
         if ([urlResponse statusCode] == 200) 
         {
             NSError *error;        
             NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData 
             options:0 error:&error];


             //resultsArray return an array [of dicitionaries<tweets>];
             NSArray* resultsArray = [dict objectForKey:@"results"]; 
             for (NSDictionary* internalDict in resultsArray)

                 NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [internalDict 
             objectForKey:@"from_user_name"]]);
        ----> return dict; // i need this dictionary of json twitter data
         }
         else
             NSLog(@"Twitter error, HTTP response: %i", [urlResponse statusCode]);
         }];
      }
```

Thnx in advance!

Comment: You're saying it's asynchronous – doesn't that mean that your method returns before the request finishes? If that's true, you can't return it from this method.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can't I return an object from my Block?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8436750/why-cant-i-return-an-object-from-my-block), [returning UIImage from block](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9474018/returning-uiimage-from-block)

Comment: What @noa said;  you need to either make the call synchronously or pass the dictionary somewhere useful from within the block.

Comment: @bbum hey hi there, thnx for the quick reply guys. I know i have to make it synchronous but how? in the twitter class the methods in .h are limited i think performRequestWithHandler was one of the only ones i saw!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I feel like I've written a ton of this async code lately.

```
- (void)tweetFetcherWithCompletion:(void(^)(NSDictionary *dict, NSError *error))completion
{
    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=iOS%205&rpp=5&with_twitter_user_id=true&result_type=recent"];
    TWRequest *request = [[TWRequest alloc] initWithURL:URL parameters:nil requestMethod:TWRequestMethodGET];

    [request performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
        if ([urlResponse statusCode] == 200) {
            NSError *error;
            NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:0 error:&error];

            if (error) {
                completion(nil, error);
                return;
            }

            //resultsArray return an array [of dicitionaries<tweets>];
            NSArray* resultsArray = [dict objectForKey:@"results"]; 
            for (NSDictionary* internalDict in resultsArray)
                NSLog(@"%@", [internalDict objectForKey:@"from_user_name"]);

            completion(dict, nil);
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"Twitter error, HTTP response: %i", [urlResponse statusCode]);
            completion(nil, error);
        }
    }];
}
```

So, instead of calling `self.tweetDict = [self TweetFetcher];`, you would call it this way.

```
[self tweetFetcherWithCompletion:^(NSDictionary *dict, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        // Handle Error Somehow
    }

    self.tweetDict = dict;
    // Everything else you need to do with the dictionary.
}];
```

Comment: Hey Jeff thnx for the help, its giving me a linker error, am i not linking a lib or should i be importing a class?  "_completion", referenced from: ___59-[UsersWithBlogsViewControllerTweetFetcherWithCompletion:]_block_invoke_0 in UsersWithBlogsViewController.o

Comment: I made a mistake in the declaration. Typing to fast I guess. It should have caused a different error, but try the new code or just modify your code.

Comment: Jeff yea i fixed the declaration and got it working! thank you very very much!!! man i feel like i have to look more in to async and threads more.. any advice? I seem to have a problem understanding the apple doc(really need to fix that). It seems like not all the information is in the same place and when you go from link to link .. it gets confusing

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite know what to say. I don't know of any good async guides, I just picked it up by making lots of mistakes and asking lots of questions. I'm not a bit fan of the Apple docs either.

Comment: Well Thnx mate, i guess ima just gonna have to mess with it more. Cheers